# Get parent context of calling context

Tags: android

I have a main activity (MyMainAvtivity), which starts a foreground service (MyForegroundService), which registers a broadcast receiver (MyUserPresentReceiver), which sets an alarm (MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver).

```
MyMainActivity
!
+-- MyForegroundService
    !
    +-- MyUserPresentReceiver
        !
        +-- MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver
```

When the alarm goes off, MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver needs to stop MyForegroundService.

I can code

```
context.stopService(intent);
```

which of course does nothing, because context is from MyUserPresentReceiver.

I can code

```
context.getApplicationContext().stopService(intent);
```

which does nothing either (I thought getApplicationContext() delivers MyForegroundService as the "global Application object of the current process", but no).

How do I get the context of MyForegroundService in MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we cannot see the codes, I cannot go beyond making a suggestion.

```
context.stopService(new Intent(context, Service.class));
```

you can try.